# Unable to translate “of” for duplicate notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, revisions-list, localization

Every question closed as duplicate contains a notice in the revision list, [e.g.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/124185/revisions):

> [image: of]

This “of” word is not used in the localization engine.
Could it please be added to the template string for closed questions to enable translation via Transifex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For today (7th of March, 2024) there is no more "of" word visible on linked in the question [revision](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/124185/revisions) for ruSO:

> [image]

Comment: Question is, is this a fix to the bug? If not (i.e. the word should appear) this report should be closed as "can no longer reproduce" and a new bug report started saying the word is missing.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda from localization PoV (for Russian language) there is no more issue here. Unfortunately I can't say anything regarding other languages.

Comment: Well the bug is "unable to translate", so it feels wrong to mark it as completed - unless a developer can confirm they did it on purpose to save the need to translate. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda: I'm guessing the entire string was reformatted to basically be translated as a whole, instead of being set so only individual portions of it could be translated, so this is no longer an issue. (I believe the relevant string currently appears in Traducir as: `**$historyType$** as "$closeReason$" by $userLinks$`.)

Comment: The word "of" was removed, as written in [this answer](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5414). If this was the case for [es.so], I assume it is also the case for the other sites.